# function not returning message from ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want my function, which does an ajax call to controller, to return message from response.

I've tried this, but it doesnt work. How can acchieve my goal? is there a better solution for this?

```
var exists = personExists ();

   if (exists != null) {
      alert('The person already exists');
      return;
   }

var personExists = function () {

   var exists = false;
   var errorMsg = null;

$.ajax({
      url: "@Url.Action("PersonExist", "Person")",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { name: self.name(), socialSecurityNumber: self.socialSecurityNumber() },
      async: false,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (response) {
          if (response.exists) {
             exists = true;
             errorMsg = response.message;
          }
      }
 });

 if (exists)
   return errorMsg;

 return null;
};
```

Comment: He set `async: false`...

Comment: Are you able to get debug point at your controller/action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with callback functions;

```
var personExists = function (callback) {

   var exists = false;
   var errorMsg = null;

    $.ajax({
          url: "@Url.Action("PersonExist", "Person")",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { name: self.name(), socialSecurityNumber: self.socialSecurityNumber() },
          async: false,
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function (response) {
              if (response.exists) {
                 exists = true;
                 errorMsg = response.message;
                 callback(exists, errorMsg);
              }
          }
     });

     if (exists)
       return errorMsg;

     return null;
};
```

And usage;

```
personExists(function(exists, err) {
    if (exists != null) {
      alert('The person already exists');
      return;
   }    
});
```

Simply, you can pass `exists` and `errorMsg` to callback. See [here](http://callbackhell.com/) for further detail on callback functions

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but im getting internal server error.

Comment: It means, you are getting error on backedn in c# code

Comment: Yes, im aware of that. It doesnt call my method in controller like it supposed to. :(

Comment: But, I didn't change anything on ajax call side

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback:

```
function getErrorMessage(message) {
    //do whatever
}
```

Inside the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "@Url.Action("PersonExist", "Person")",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { name: self.name(), socialSecurityNumber: self.socialSecurityNumber() },
  async: false,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (response) {
      if (response.exists) {
         exists = true;
         getErrorMessage(response.message); //callback
      }
  }
```

});